# Wallet management now that accounts are deprecated?

Tags: wallet, json-rpc, website-integration

I'm building a website which will allow every user to make deposits and transact with Bitcoin, how will I be able to get the balance of a specific wallet. I currently know these commands:

`$bitcoin->createwallet("wallet_name");`

But to get the wallet info of that specific wallet is confusing for me, according to the documentation the `getwalletinfo` RPC takes no parameters. So my question is how do you get wallet information of a specific wallet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using more than one wallet, the wallet is selected by sending the RPC requests to `<host:port>/wallet/<wallet_name>`.

Comment: how would that look in PHP?

Comment: I don't do PHP, but it should just be a matter of update the URL you are sending the request to so that it includes the wallet path.

Comment: I tried to run this in command line: `bitcoin-cli getwalletinfo "home/username/bitcoin/wallets/testwallet"` which returns an `error code`

Comment: Just for clarification, my OS is linux

Comment: If you are using bitcoin-cli, you need to set the `-rpcwallet=<wallet_name>` parameter - the url based selection is for applications using the RPC interface directly

Comment: so if i were to use it via my application i'd still have to have that in the `bitcoin.conf`?

Comment: The bitcoin folder and their wallets aren't located within the server directory

Comment: again how do I do it in the url when my bitcoin sevrer isn't located within my web server?